# Only printing one line of csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to print every line in a csv file however it will only print the first one.
Heres the code that is responsible:

```
    if option == '1':
    with open("songs.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            output = (row[0], row[1], row[2]) #Only outputs 1 song ?
            print (output)
```

Here is the full code if needed:

```
def list():
option = input ('Enter 1 to print a list of all songs or Enter 2 to print songs in a certin genre: ')
if option == '1':
    with open("songs.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            output = (row[0], row[1], row[2]) #Only outputs 1 song ?
            print (output)

            outputtxt_check = False

            while outputtxt_check == False:
                outputtxt = input ("Would you like to output this list to a text file? Enter 1 for yes or 2 for no: ")

                if outputtxt == '1':
                    text_file = open('list.txt', 'w')
                    text_file.write(str(output))
                    text_file.close()
                    outputtxt_check = True
                    print ("Text File Created Successfully!")
                    menu()

                elif outputtxt == '2':
                    (list)
                    outputtxt_check = True
                    menu()

                else:
                    print('Enter 1 or 2')
                    outputtxt_check = False
                    list()
```

Thank You in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure your csv file contains more than 1 lines?

Comment: yes it has multiple

Comment: can you provide first 2 lines of your csv file?

Comment: It's printing all lines for me.

Comment: i bet my life,imagine dragons,indie / 
its time,imagine dragons,indie

Comment: Are you sure you want "outputtxt_check = False" and "while outputtxt_check == False:" inside your "for row in reader:"? It will do that after it reads the first line (and everytime you read a line). I imagine you want that after it reads the whole file.

Comment: maybe you need a dos2unix or unix2dos before reading your file

Comment: Don't know if you have some limitation in terms of not being able to use pandas, but it seems to be much simpler (and faster) to just import the whole data into a DataFrame using pandas.read_csv() and then filtering by genre if the user asks for it instead of reading line by line and saving the data into a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the code where you list the songs is working for me.

```
if option == '1':
    with open("songs.csv") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            output = (row[0], row[1], row[2]) #Only outputs 1 song ?
            print (output)
```

However, the stuff you write after, while it is looping, e.g.

```
outputtxt_check = False

                while outputtxt_check == False:
                    outputtxt = input(
                        "Would you like to output this list to a text file? Enter 1 for yes or 2 for no: ")
```

is happening while in the same for loop. That's why it's printing only one line. You're asking user the question while the for loop is not finished printing all the songs yet. Try putting the while loop outside/after for loop is done.

Comment: what  I do for  csv a list the whole lot. So now, you have a list of lists. Then ask for  row[0] and row[1].  As for your  issue I think you should use Exception handling. (IOE)